# 500 Server Error - FastHosts & Windows

Tags: hosting, error-500

We've just pushed a website on to a clients server... Sadly, he's chosen his own hosting and gone with Fasthosts, and Windows!?

After activating PHP and MySQL on the server, we've hit two problems:

- When it's in the root folder, it gives us a **"500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."** error. No matter if we go to the front end or ExpressionEngine admin itself
- When it's in a sub-folder, we get a different error - **"The service is unavailable."**

Would you say this is a hosting issue, or some settings we need to tweak?

We've ran the Server Wizard and everything is marked as yes.

Is there anything we coudl check to see whats going on? It's a shared host, so there is no logs on the server, or CP that I can see of!

Comment: did you try just create some test php file? like <?php php_info();?> ? What php version you have?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like it could be something to do with your htaccess file. Try removing bits from it and see if the site begins to (sort of) work. At least that will tell you where to look.

Comment: I've tried this, I also tried deleting it but nothing changed. I might contact Fasthosts to see if there is already a hidden htaccess on the server overwriting my settings.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to create test file, like test_info_.php

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

if you will get info, try to upload and run some [EE compatibility tests](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html#server-compatibility-wizard).  Possible some libraries is not available on this hosting.

Comment: I did also try this. I ran the EE Wizard and everything was available on the server. Really bizarre.